# html2canvas doesnt work when elements are zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, screenshot, html2canvas

I'm taking a screenshot of my webpage using the html2canvas plugin and it works really well. 
However, one of the divs on the page can be zoomed, which seems to cause problems when the screenshot is taken. 
This is the code which takes the screenshot.

```
 function screenshot(fileName){

        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var image = myImage.replace('data:image/png;base64','');
                window.open(myImage);
            }

         });
```

Is there an easy way to update the dom so that when the div is zoomed, html2canvas takes a screenshot of the latest webpage, or is this not possible.

Does anybody have any experience of working with any other plugins which may be a good alternative?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean "one of the divs on the page can be zoomed"?

Comment: @Xanco you Ctrl+Scroll the page, it means, you zoom it

Answer (score -2):

Try to write below lines of code just below your code to zoom div / image in javascript

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var image = myImage.replace('data:image/png;base64','');
        window.open(myImage);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're just saying move the code to a different place in the script?

Comment: please explain you copied the same code as the OP